# Passing BluetoothDevice Object to Another Activity though Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth

I'm writing bluetooth client and I have a problem.
My first activity display enabled devices in ListView. When click on some item on this list, it should start new activity and pass a BluetoothDevice object there. I write something like that:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if(listAdapter.getItem(position).contains("Paired")) {

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, BTActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("btdevice", selectedDevice);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to pass BluetoothDevice object to another activity? How to extract this object in new activity?

Sorry for my English. If something isn't clear, I will try explain better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes . It is possible since `BluetoothDevice` class `implements` `Parcelable`

You can get the object in other `Activity` like this

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("btdevice");
```

Make sure getIntent().getExtras() is not null